# Apache or NGINX + GitHub runner

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, ubuntu-20.04, github, github-actions

I have a development server that I'm currently using for beta-level production (mostly sending out to my clients for proof of work). So what I wanna do is use my runner to automatically sync with main branch (which I'm doing right now without any issues). However, I wanna automate my process a bit further. Basically, what I wanna do is every time I assign a project with the runner I also want apache to be auto-set to the project name with subdomain. For example, if I have a project named test-project and then when the runner is assigned to the project and picked up I want apache to set up test-project.example.com automatically. So that I won't be going through the process every time

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with performance in web servers, having the potential of handling static content along side dynamic content is significantly important. As reported  by a benchmark take a look at performed by running up to 1,000 concurrent connections, NGINX performs 2 and half times quicker than Apache in static contents. will be} by no surprise because of the actual fact that NGINX’s RAM usage is below Apache in handling requests, so faster it can work.

With dynamic content, virtually each of them act within the same way. One and solely distinction is that the ability to method dynamic content natively. Apache cashes in on embedding a processor into every of its employee instances, whereas NGINX should use Associate in Nursing external processor to handle dynamic content requests.